# Hazelcast IMDG String to HazelcastJsonValue issue

Tags: java, json, type-conversion, hazelcast

Hazel cast IMDG String to HazelcastJsonValue conversion is not happening .

Issue Statement - Storing json as string format in HazelCast IMDG . Retrieving using HazelcastJsonValue  ..Getting below exception

Please help to resolve the issue .

If `HazelcastJsonValue` object is stored in hazelcast IMDG .. it's working. 
But `String` to `HazelcastJsonValue` is not working. Getting following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.hazelcast.query.QueryException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no suitable accessor for 'age' on class 'java.lang.String'
    at com.hazelcast.query.impl.getters.ReflectionHelper.createGetter(ReflectionHelper.java:171)
    at com.hazelcast.query.impl.getters.Extractors.instantiateGetter(Extractors.java:152)
    at com.hazelcast.query.impl.getters.Extractors.getGetter(Extractors.java:118)
    at com.hazelcast.query.impl.getters.Extractors.extract(Extractors.java:73)
```

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    HazelcastInstance instance = com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config());
    String person1 = "{ \"name\": \"John\", \"age\": 35 }";
    String person2 = "{ \"name\": \"Jane\", \"age\": 24 }";
    String person3 = "{ \"name\": \"Trey\", \"age\": 17 }";
    //Storing as String
    IMap<Integer, String> idPersonMap = instance.getMap("jsonValues");
    idPersonMap.put(1, person1);
    idPersonMap.put(2, person2);
    idPersonMap.put(3, person3);

    //Retrieving as HazelcastJsonValue
    IMap<Integer, HazelcastJsonValue> idPersonMapRead =  instance.getMap("jsonValues");
    Collection<HazelcastJsonValue> peopleUnder21 = (Collection<HazelcastJsonValue>) idPersonMapRead.values(Predicates.lessThan("age", 50));
    System.out.println( "-------------------Result--------------------");
    System.out.println( peopleUnder21.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()));

}

 public static Config config(){
        Config config = new Config();
        config.setInstanceName("hazelcast-instance")
                .addMapConfig(
                        new MapConfig().setMetadataPolicy(MetadataPolicy.OFF)
                                .setName("configuration")
                                .setMaxSizeConfig(new MaxSizeConfig(200, MaxSizeConfig.MaxSizePolicy.FREE_HEAP_SIZE))
                                .setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.LRU)
                                .setTimeToLiveSeconds(-1));

        return config;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You put `String` instances into the `IMap`. Don't expect `HazelcastJsonValue` instances to be returned by the `get` operation. It will be `String` again.

When you call the method `get`, it doesn't know about your target
generic type. For user's convenience, Hazelcast doesn't return a raw type, but
it does an unchecked conversion underhood.

If you want to have automatic value conversion within the put
operation, you can use a `MapInterceptor` for instance:

```java
IMap<Integer, String> idPersonMap = instance.getMap("jsonValues");
idPersonMap.addInterceptor(new ConvertOnPutMapInterceptor());

    private static class ConvertOnPutMapInterceptor implements MapInterceptor {

        @Override
        public Object interceptGet(Object value) {
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public void afterGet(Object value) {
        }

        @Override
        public Object interceptPut(Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
            return new HazelcastJsonValue((String) newValue);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterPut(Object value) {
        }

        @Override
        public Object interceptRemove(Object removedValue) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void afterRemove(Object value) {
        }
    }
```